# How to check if L293D IC is working or not with a multimeter?

Tags: integrated-circuit, multimeter, debugging, motordriver

I know it is probably better to toss out a doubtful IC for a new one, but I would like to know if there is a way to check if the IC is faulty using a DMM.

Comment: probably check the voltage outputs when using it, does it output high when it should be high and low when it should be low?

Comment: Do you mean in circuit, or out of circuit?

Comment: @HandyHowie out of circuit

Comment: You can only have a guaranteed good IC if you test its full functionality in a circuit. Out-of-circuit you can only detect specific some errors (not all errors/faults) and it would require comparing to a known-good device. In the end: it is not worth the trouble for such a cheap IC.

Comment: Got it, thank you